# Accessing and encoding of properties files

Tags: java, properties

I'm used to work with properties files, for example from Ant.  Where I can simply reference the property file doing something like that:

```
<property file="webapp_DO_NOT_COMMIT.properties"/>
```

(the file is so named because our DVCS is configured as to never commit files containing "DO_NOT_COMMIT" to prevent committing credentials/passwords/etc.)

Here's a very simple *.properties* file example:

```
passwd=brokencleartextpassword
```

Now I want to put some configuration in another, similar, properties file that I need to access from my Java code.  How should I go about it?

I also have another related question: is the character encoding of *.properties* file defined by any spec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it in the classpath and then load it by [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
```

As to the encoding, it's ISO-8859-1, as specified in the API javadoc.

> ... the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. ...

But you can go around it by feeding a `Reader` instead (which is new since Java 1.6).

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties");
properties.load(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

#### See also:

- [Properties tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: +1, thanks a lot! I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me do so :)